# CSV File reading slash ("/") in latex table

Tags: csv, csvsimple

I have csv file having 6 columns where first column have "/" in it. I am using below code:

```
\documentclass{article}



\usepackage{csvsimple}
\usepackage{datatool}
\begin{document}

\DTLloadrawdb[keys={a,b,c,d,e,f},headers={a,b,c,d,e,f}]{t2g}{table.csv}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}\hline
\DTLdisplaydb{t2g}
\\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

But I am getting below error

```
! Argument of \@dtl@qlopoff has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.303 ...d,e,f}]{t2g}{table.csv}
```

My sample csv file looks like

```
a                    b             c     d   e  f
bhupinder/example      ubuntu:14.04 838 528 19  example
bhupinder/freesurfer    ubuntu:14.04 353 298 13 freesurfer
bhupinder/ndmg          ubuntu:14.04 934 538 20 ndmg
bhupinder/broccoli:v1.0.0   centos 6  79 253 54 broccoli
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: you should provide a sample csv that shows the problem also you say backslash (which is `\ `) but you show a forward slash (`/`)  so with no example csv file it is hard to guess what the issue is.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle edited my question. Thanks

Comment: you had only posted a fragment not a test document, I made it a test document. for me it runs without error, but all the data goes in column **a** as there are no commas to separate the values in the csv file.